# Limited matrices in Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix

How come the `Matrix` class has no methods to edit its vectors and components? It seems like everything inside a matrix can be read but not written. Am I mistaken? Is there some third-party elegant `Matrix`-like class that would allow me to delete rows and intentionally edit them?

Please, notify me if there is no such class – I will stop searching.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with it?

Comment: I'm looking for 'bad' rows and columns (which entirely consist of zeros), and then I would like to delete 'em. I already have the code to do that, but written completely via Arrays. Nevertheless I'm trying to find more precise and pretty solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The designer of class `Matrix` must have been a fan of immutable data structures and functional programming. Yes, you are correct.

In any case, there is a simple solution for what you want. Use `Matrix` for what it can do, then, just use `.to_a` to get a real array.

```
>> Matrix.identity(2).to_a
=> [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

See also [Numerical Ruby Narray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/). You could also monkeypatch the class to add more behavior. If you do this, please patch a subclass of Matrix. (There are Ruby library projects out there that want more behavior from `require`d classes so they directly modify them, making their new files somewhat toxic. They could have so easily just patched a subclass or singleton class.)

Oh, and [khelll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124504/khelll) (:-) would probably like me to say that there is quite possibly a way for you to do what you want [in a functional style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). That is, by creating new objects rather than by modifying the old ones.

Comment: +1 for mentioning immutability and functional programming, that's why I asked what you want to do exactly, cause there should be a way to it but without modifying the current matrix.