# Ruby core Matrix vs NArray's NMatrix

Tags: ruby, arrays, math, vector, matrix

There seems to be three matrix modules in Ruby that I've found

- [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/classes/Matrix.html): Part of core Ruby it seems
- [NArray](http://masa16.github.io/narray/matrix-e.html): NMatrix is part of the NArray library ([github](https://github.com/masa16/narray))
- [NMatrix](https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix): Part of SciRuby

At the moment it seems `NArray`'s `NMatrix` is faster than `Matrix`, has some more helpful methods, but require a bit more setup.

Is there anyone with experience of both who can give a rough overview of why I should use one over the other?

Comment: There's also [mdarray](https://github.com/rbotafogo/mdarray) for JRuby, it's not compatible with MRI as it uses Colt library written in Java (though, it might be interesting to compare all of these libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stumbling on this question now... It's been 7 months since you've asked, so I'm sure you've found your answer by now.

However, please find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486484/limited-matrices-in-ruby).

Basically, the author of the core Matrix class did not add methods to perform run-time modifications to the array once it is instantiated. The **[NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/)** class allows for this.

As far as computation time, I'll leave that to somebody else, for I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the ballgame, but have you seen the new NMatrix gem? It's inspired by NArray. It's also written in C/C++, whereas Ruby Matrix is written only in Ruby --- so NMatrix is definitely faster.

That's also true for NArray, which is C-only.

The advantage to using NMatrix instead of `NArray::NMatrix` is that you can choose between different storage types (sparse, dense, etc.).