# How to modify a matrix (Ruby std-lib Matrix class)?

Tags: ruby, matrix

I understood it that Ruby stdlib Matrix is not modifiable, that is, for eg.

```
m = Matrix.zero( 3, 4 )
```

one cannot write

```
m[0, 1] = 7
```

But I would like to do it so much... I can do it with awkward programming, such as

```
def modify_value_in_a_matrix( matrix, row, col, newval )
  ary = (0...m.row_size).map{ |i| m.row i }.map( &:to_a )
  ary[row][col] = newval
  Matrix[ *ary ]
end
```

...or with cheating, such as

```
Matrix.send :[]=, 0, 1, 7
```

, but I wonder, this has to be a problem that people encounter all the time. Is there some standard, customary way of doing this, without having to rape the class using #send method?

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486484/limited-matrices-in-ruby?

Comment: Which goes to show that indeed the ppl encounter this all the time. So what now?

Comment: Interesting. Check out the solution provided at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/161792#710996 Seems like an elegant way to have this functionality.

Comment: I'd say get the array and change the values. Matrix was made immutable for a reason.

Comment: I'm just reading the discussion that Prakash pitched, it's very enlightening.

Comment: Have you looked at [NMatrix](https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the class and def your own method to do this:

```
class Matrix
  def []=(i, j, x)
    @rows[i][j] = x
  end
end
```

Comment: I would not want to override existing #[]= method, but it's an interesting idea to take use of #[]= "legally" from inside the method. I do not share excessive aversion of some programmers to modification of native classes.

Comment: Anyway, Marc Andre told me he's gonna make Matrix mutable in the future.

Answer (score 10):

Why would you open the class to redefine a method that already exists ?

```
class Matrix
  public :"[]=", :set_element, :set_component
end
```